# NLog Custom LayoutRenderer not working

Tags: logging, error-handling, nlog

I have a custom `LayoutRenderer` defined as follows for `NLog` in a common assembly:

```
[LayoutRenderer("appsettings")]
public class AppSettingsLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer {
    [DefaultParameter]
    public string Variable {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent) {
        if (Variable == null) {
            return;
        }

        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        if (context == null) {
            return;
        }

        builder.Append(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Variable], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

This common assembly is referenced in 2 projects where I have implemented logging.

The first project is an ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC website and configured as a top level web site.

The second project is a WCF project hosting multiple services under IIS and configured as a virtual directory under another website (the default website in IIS).

Both contain the following in their `Web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ErrorLogPath" value="D:\Logs" />
</appSettings>
```

Both projects reference the common assembly (which contains the customer `LayoutRenderer`). I have verified that the `bin` folders for both projects actually contain the assembly DLL as well. I confirmed this via the paths configured in IIS.

Finally, both projects contain the following `NLog.config` file alongside the `Web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="Collective.Core" />
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}${onexception:inner=${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}" fileName="${appsettings:ErrorLogPath}\${logger}\${shortdate}.log" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Both projects run under the same app pool.

Now, my problem:

For the first project, the logs appear in the correct place, i.e., `D:\Logs\Logger.Name\yyyy-MM-dd.log`.

For the second, the logs appear in `C:\Logger.Name\yyyy-MM-dd.log`.

What's going on? The configuration and enabling code is identical, yet the logs appear in 2 different locations consistently, one intended and the other unintended.

For the life of me, I cannot understand what's going on.

Comment: In WCF the `HttpContext.Current;` will be always **null**... so the `builder.Append` won't be called... From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx): HttpContext: Current is always null when accessed from within a WCF service. Use RequestContext instead.

Comment: I had actually sorted that problem out but I would mark your comment as an answer for the MSDN reference on the HttpContext being always null in WCF. If you like, please add your answer as a comment to allow me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different results in your projects because in WCF the `HttpContext.Current` **is always `null`**...

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx):

> HttpContext: Current is always null when accessed from within a WCF service. Use RequestContext instead.

And because of your

```
if (context == null) {
    return;
}
```

statement your `builder.Append` won't be called... so NLog defaults to the base `LayoutRenderer` behavior.